# how to get list of public images of aws using pkgcloud?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pkgcloud

i am trying to launch instance on aws using pkgcloud so for that image option is must, so i used bellow code to get list of images.

```
aws = pkgcloud.compute.createClient({
        provider:'amazon',
        key:'',
        keyId:''
    });
aws.getImages(function (err, images) { 
        console.log(images);
    });
```

but above API returns empty array. so how do i get list of all public images available on aws?

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and could not find any answer. So I stopped using pkgcloud and started with aws-sdk instead which is directly provided by Amazon. It has much better documentation and works like a charm.